# How can I create a DispatcherObject with a new Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I am working on a project where I have multiple instances of a `DispatcherObject`-inheriting class that contains a `Model3D`. I need these instances to asynchronously update their models (change vertices, normals, etc) via a method called `Update()`. `Update()` will spin off a thread that does some computations and applies the new vertices, normals, etc.

The models can be of varying complexity, and simply dispatching the update to the same UI dispatcher is slow (see code sample below). This update would need to happen multiple times per second (anywhere from 20 to 500 Hz). I am wondering if there is some simple way to allow multiple threads to update the UI simultaneously.

```
public void Update()
{
    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Do some computations to decide new vertices, normals...

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    // Apply new vertices, normals to model.
                    // Note: There could be thousands of vertices
                }
        });

    th.Start();
}
```

I am aware of setting the apartment state of the thread to STA and calling `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()` inside the thread, but that only seems to work for multi-window applications. In my case, the models are rendered inside the same `Viewport3D` and hence the same window.

I also looked into using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` to create a new dispatcher when needed, but that didn't seem to work.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is no. There is no simple way since the UI work is performed on a single thread. You could however do your computations on different threads and then use some piping mechanism to communicate the computed actions to be performed to the GUI thread.

Comment: Well, I am already doing the computations on the background thread. The problem arises when I need to update the UI. I am already communicating the changes by way of the dispatcher. Based on what I have read so far, it seems there is no way to have multiple UI threads (and hence multiple dispatchers) update the same window...

Comment: What would you gain by updating the GUI from multiple threads? My thought was that you might want to prioritize some of the requests to the GUI or else realize they may be redundant because of some other thread's computations.